# How JavaScript store unstored values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator

I am trying to write a code using ES6 iterators :

```
let numbers = [100,200,300];

let iter = numbers[Symbol.iterator]();

iter.next(); // statement 1
iter.next(); // statement 2
console.log(iter.next()); // statement 3
```

How does javascript store the values of "***statement 1***" and "***statement 2***"?

Comment: Why would they be stored if they are unused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't.

1. You call the iterator `next` function.
2. It gets the value.
3. It forwards the iterator.
4. It returns the value from step 2.
5. You discard the value because you don't assign it anywhere.